# SQL Server: What is the best way to Data Migration?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-migration

I want to migrate data from one database to another database in Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I need to verify those rows retrieved before I insert them to the destination database's tables. Which approach is reasonable for this kind of things?

I am trying to use two datasets in my VB.NET program. Is it reasonable? Can you suggest me?

Thanks in advance,

RedsDevils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how much data you're talking about, but I'd tend to pass on .Net datasets for a migration task, as that means pulling all the data into memory.  If you *must* do this via a .Net client program, at least use a DataReader instead.  But what's even better is to keep it all in Sql Server via [Sql Server Integration Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Data records about 100000 over. I want to import. Can you show me .Net datasets example in migration?